# Why Elasticsearch and Kibana generating garbage data ceaselessly?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just installed Elasticsearch and Kibana. X-pack has been enable. I never put any data into Elasticsearch, but when I use Kibana to monitor elasticsearch, I found the number of data increased automatically. I have to stop Elasticsearch and Kibana to make it stop. Why this phenomenon happen? And how can I fix it?

PS: Elasticsearch and Kibana version is 7.11.1.

The increasing number of data: kibana>stack monitoring>Elasticsearch>Overview>data.
The red part was from: 2M ---> 314M, I don't know what it done.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you be more precise? What data are you talking about?

Comment: kibana>stack monitoring>Elasticsearch>Overview>data

Comment: What kind of data? I don't see what you see... Help us help you. Go to Stack management > Index management and sort indexes by size, what do you see?

Comment: Maybe I should put a img into the question, wait a moment

Comment: the number of Document is also increasing.

Comment: Stack Monitoring doesn't help here... Go to Stack management > Index management and sort indexes by size, what do you see?

Comment: this page shows only two indexes, one is vehicle, another one is metrics-endpoint.metadata_current_default. But both of them are very small. Is it possible that kibana makes a lot garbage? The JVM value is also growing. Please view the new img which is following the question. Thank U.

Comment: Can you turn on the switch to see the system indexes ?